# Are there any files or folders (apart from robots.txt and favicon.ico) which MUST go in the root directory according to their official spec?

Tags: files, document-root, folder-structure

I know that

- `Robots Exclusion Protocol (robots.txt)`
- `Other similar .txt protocols` (including `sellers.json`)
- `favicon.ico`

**must** be placed in the root directory (according to their official spec), like this:

- `/ads.txt`
- `/favicon.ico`
- `/humans.txt`
- `/robots.txt`
- `/sellers.json`

What about:

- `/.well-known/` ?

Must `/.well-known/` also be placed in the root directory according to its official spec?

Are there any other files or folders which **must** be placed in the root directory?

Comment: Technically nothing has to be placed in the document root directory of your web server.  Even if a document has to be served from the root of your URL, you can use server configuration such as `Alias` or `RewriteRule` to serve it from any directory of your choosing.

Comment: See also [What is the .well-known/ directory and how should I set it up?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/96427/what-is-the-well-known-directory-and-how-should-i-set-it-up).  The `.well-known` RFC is an attempt to "fix" this "problem".  In the future anybody that creates a URL that should be on every website should no longer put it at the root of the site, but rather prefix the URL path with `/.well-known/`.  If people follow that RFC, there shouldn't be any additional URLs created that need to be at the root of your site.

Comment: This is definitely reassuring to learn, @StephenOstermiller. I'd wondered if it would be legitimate to `301 Redirect` a `robots.txt` file using Apache `.htaccess` `mod_rewrite` or if search engines would simply ignore a `301 redirected` protocol. Nevertheless, in this case, I'm unsure I can take advantage of redirection - my underlying issue is that I want to be able to set up one or more non-root site configurations in the same webspace. If there were only one I could certainly redirect from `/robots.txt` to `/my-site-configuration/robots.txt`... but if I have more...

Comment: I also like the idea of using `/.well-known/` for all standard configuration and protocol files. I really like this idea. But I can't find `/.well-known/robots.txt` in the wild anywhere.

Comment: `robots.txt ` was created before `.well-known`.  The RFC for `.well-known` states that it only applies to URLs created in the future.   URLs such as `/robots.txt` that existed beforehand will remain at their current root URL.

Comment: It is possible (even easy) to customize robots.txt per domain using rewrite rules when multiple sites are served from the same directory.   It can be done using internal rewrites, so you don't even need to use redirection.   You should ask that as a separate question as it would not be appropriate for me to hide the solution in a comment here.

Comment: You should ask "How do I serve separate robots.txt files for two Apache sites served out of the same directory?"

Comment: [Robots.txt for multiple domains with same website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83922/robots-txt-for-multiple-domains-with-same-website)

Comment: The real question would seem to be "What URLs must be accessible from the root to satisfy 3rd party requests", rather than "what files/folders must go (stored) in the root."

Comment: Yes, @MrWhite, sorry if that wasn't clear from the question. When I wrote _"must go in the root directory"_, I meant _"according to their official spec"_.

Answer (score 2):

> Must `/.well-known/` also be placed in the root directory?

The `/.well-known/` prefix is a [defined standard (RFC8615)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8615), to which specific URI suffixes can be [officially registered](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8615#section-5.1). So yes, it would need to reside in the root directory.

More info:
https://serverfault.com/questions/795467/for-what-is-the-well-known-folder

Others I can think of, off hand...

- `humans.txt`
- Google site HTML verification file: `google123...html`
- Bing site HTML verification file: `BingSiteAuth.xml`
- Other site verification files ... whilst for most this list is probably limited, if you include all possible 3rd party services then this list has potential to grow significantly?!

Of course, they don't necessarily need to *physically* exist in the site root, but they need to be accessible via the site root URL (if at all).

Comment: Thanks, @MrWhite. Just to clarify, are you stating it isn't the case that `/.well-known/` **must** be in the root directory? If it can go elsewhere without breaking things then I'll be happy to remove it from the _must be in the root directory_ list.

Comment: No, it _must_ be available in the root directory. The `/.well-known/` prefix is a [defined standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8615). Whilst this location can perhaps be configured for certain services, if you are on a shared server you will have less control over this. Sorry, my answer wasn't particularly clear, I'll update it...

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be difficult to get an exhaustive list of all possible files which need to live at the root. For one thing, different content management systems may place various files at the root, while others may place those elsewhere, so it depends on what platform you're using.

Generally, your `index.html` file will be found at the root, but keep in mind that your root is still a folder, which may have different names, depending on your web host or your CMS.

Then, you have changing standards. The `sitemap.xml` file used to be commonly be placed at the root, but these days many CMS's like WordPress (via plugins like Yoast) allow for creation of a `sitemap_index.xml` file, which then leads to a list of sitemaps broken down by content type. Sometimes, they all live at the root; other times, they're in a directory. Having them in a directory is okay, as long as the sitemap index file is at the root and the search bots can easily find and crawl that directory. Thus, the `sitemap.xml` file may not exist on a website at all anymore, replaced by a (slightly) more complex sitemap information architecture. [More on WordPress XML sitemaps here.](https://yoast.com/what-is-an-xml-sitemap-and-why-should-you-have-one/)

And then you have specific use cases. If your website is a publisher and actively sells inventory for ads to display on, you need an `ads.txt` file. This file should be at the root. If you're an ad exchange or an SSP (sell side platform), you need a `sellers.json` file, which should also live at the root. Read more about [ads.txt](https://ppcprotect.com/what-is-ads-txt/) and [sellers.json](https://www.indexexchange.com/what-sellers-and-buyers-should-know-about-sellers-json-schain-and-transparency/).

Perhaps the best way to go about it is, learn more about your CMS, figure out the functionality you're looking for, and follow the standard, where the documentation will tell you where the crucial files should live.

For a look at how WordPress does it, [here's a starter article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-wordpress-file-and-directory-structure/).

Comment: Thanks, @HenryVisotski. To clarify, I'm not looking for "can be in the root directory" or "is usually found in the root directory" or even "should be in the root directory" - only "MUST be in the root directory".

Comment: Re: "learn more about your CMS" - heh, I'm _writing_ a CMS. That's why I'm asking the question at the top - to verify I've not missed any files or folders which have a fixed, pre-designated location.

Comment: Writing a CMS? Now that's cool! @Rounin I'd say take a look at what WP and Drupal are doing, they're so well established that their lead is good to follow or to get ideas from. This is a good starting point for WP: https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-wordpress-file-and-directory-structure/ . Also, besides the `index.html` file, you'll want the `.htaccess` file at the root.

Comment: Link added to the response, @Rounin - thanks for the feedback! Yeah, if your CMS is different, then probably only the robots.txt and ads.txt, as that's the expected location if you're a bot. Ads.txt is now crucial if you are a publisher trying to monetize; I'm an ad tech eng so I can vouch for that. Favicon should be in the same folder as index file, but that's also optional; see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359342/is-putting-your-favicon-ico-file-in-a-non-root-path-a-bad-idea

Comment: "Then, you have changing standards. The `sitemap.xml` file used to be commonly be placed at the root" - The sitemap XML file never needed to be located in the site root and it never needed to be called "sitemap.xml" - that was simply a convenience that sites tended to adopt. Regardless of where it is or what it's called you still needed to inform search engines where to find it.

Comment: Still @MrWhite, I'd say for a long time it was the expected place to put it, so much so that you very rarely saw it elsewhere. Technically you can of course include it three folders deep, submit that in GSC, and make sure it's not blocked for crawlers, but very few did it that way, at least in earlier days of SEO, since "expected" was also "preferred."